# Drag and drop between levels in a list

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want a list with reorderable items that can go up and down levels in a hierarchy, like http://tamagokun.github.io/example-react-dnd-nested/ or the behavior in Notion.so's outline views:

[image]

From what I can tell, the most robust reorderable widget out there, [reorderables](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables), only supports within-level dragging, not between-level dragging (see the Nested ReorderableWrap Demo).

Are there any packages or recommended approaches to take to make an arbitrarily recursive, reorderable list? Is this dynamic behavior possible in Flutter currently?

Comment: I am working on a two level list view at the moment, I got myself started using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53763226/4791411) and changing many things to make it work how I want. the package suggested only allow to use a simple list but nothing stops us from forming the list with different widgets (with the tree-level spacing needed on the left side) that we created using a data tree.
I will post here as an answer my working solution once finished and maybe later if I have time will try to make my own package to do so.

Comment: @jan Have you do this kind of list?

Comment: Have you achieved? If yes, then please provide resource.