# Flutter: Why is my ReorderableList not registering my drag?

Tags: flutter, dart, reorderable-list

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableList(
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {},
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
        key: ValueKey(index),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: const ListTile(
          title: Text("hey!"),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
          tileColor: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
      itemCount: 5,
    );
  }
}
```

I have made this ChatPage just to test the results in a super easy, not conflicting with anything, way, but my drag is not detected and i can't reorder my list!

I know the "onReorder" is not filled out, so it would not save my changes, but I cant drag the tiles at all:/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something speak against using ReorderableListView.builder?

```
ReorderableListView.builder(
    onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {},
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
      key: ValueKey(index),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: const ListTile(
        title: Text("hey!"),
        contentPadding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
        tileColor: Colors.green,
      ),
    ),
    itemCount: 5,
  );
```

Comment: Yes, the ReorderableListView.builder works! Nice! What is the difference between them? Shouldn't the ReorderableList work aswell?

On the real page I am using SliverReorderableList, which does not have an equivalent "...View.builder".

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think it is about the drag handles. With the ReorderableListView.builder the parameter buildDefaultDragHandles is set to true. While the ReorderableListView does not have drag handles by default. Also the behavior is different on web and on mobile. On mobile the long press works to drag the list elements while on the web the dedicated drag handle is needed.
This answer contains some more information about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751987/14729495

Comment: I ended up using a ReorderableDragStartListener in my SliverReorderableList. This worked! Thanks alot!